# Problem connect Redux with parent props from React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have been trying for several days to solve a problem between connect of redux and a props of a parent component. I use redux in my child component and at the same time use props to call a handlechange function and a state of the parent component.

When in the child component use connect does not update this.props.args properly, however in the parent there is no problem. Then I have a validation so that when all the fields are complete, my submit button will be activated.

Additionally implement a state and a function in the parent component to detect the movement of the mouse and pass it to the child component, to clear some doubts, the amazing thing is that in this case if it detects changes in this.props.mouse and much more rare is that when I fill a field and then move the mouse, my this.props.args in the child component if it is updated. I'm a little disconcerted and I do not know what is due.

**Parent Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SignUp from './login/SignUp';


class Login extends Component {

    state = {
        showRegister: true,
        argsSignup: {},
        move: {},
    }

    handleChange = (ev, input) => {
        let argsSignup = this.state.argsSignup;
        argsSignup[input.name] = input.value;
        this.setState({argsSignup});
        //console.log(this.state.argsSignup);
    }

    handleMouseMove = (event) => {
        this.setState({
        move: {
                x: event.clientX,
                y: event.clientY
        }
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {showRegister, argsSignup, move} = this.state;

        return(
            <div onMouseMove={this.handleMouseMove}>
                {showRegister && <SignUp args={argsSignup} handleChange={this.handleChange} mouse={move} />}                                            
            </div>
        );                
    }
}


export default (Login);
```

**Child Component (with connect):**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Form, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { signInFacebook } from "../../redux/createActions";
class SignUp extends Component {    

    render() {
        const {args, handleChange, signInFacebook} = this.props;
        return(
            <React.Fragment >           
                <Form >
                    <Form.Field>
                        <Form.Input name='email' onChange={handleChange} placeholder='numero de movil o correo electronico' />                        
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field>
                        <Form.Input name='name' onChange={handleChange} placeholder='Nombre completo'/>                        
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field>
                        <Form.Input name='username' onChange={handleChange} placeholder='Nombre de usuario' />
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field>
                        <Form.Input name='password' onChange={handleChange} type="password" placeholder='contraseña' />
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Button 
                        type='submit' 
                        disabled={!args.email || !args.username || !args.name || !args.password }
                        primary 
                        fluid>
                            Regístrate
                    </Button>                        
                </Form>
                <button onClick={signInFacebook}>Inicia sesion con Facebook</button>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}


export default connect(null, {signInFacebook})(SignUp);
```

On the other hand, if I delete the connect from my child component, everything works great and if it detects the changes of this.props.args

**Child Component (without connect):**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Form, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { signInFacebook } from "../../redux/createActions";
class SignUp extends Component {    

    render() {
        const {args, handleChange, signInFacebook} = this.props;
        return(
            <React.Fragment >           
                <Form >
                    <Form.Field>
                        <Form.Input name='email' onChange={handleChange} placeholder='numero de movil o correo electronico' />                        
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field>
                        <Form.Input name='name' onChange={handleChange} placeholder='Nombre completo'/>                        
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field>
                        <Form.Input name='username' onChange={handleChange} placeholder='Nombre de usuario' />
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Form.Field>
                        <Form.Input name='password' onChange={handleChange} type="password" placeholder='contraseña' />
                    </Form.Field>
                    <Button 
                        type='submit' 
                        disabled={!args.email || !args.username || !args.name || !args.password }
                        primary 
                        fluid>
                            Regístrate
                    </Button>                        
                </Form>
                <button onClick={signInFacebook}>Inicia sesion con Facebook</button>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}


export default (SignUp);
```

I appreciate your help from now on. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you `connect` your component, you are establishing a connection with Redux and the props of that component will be fed by the entire application state.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {signInFacebook})(SignUp);
```

Your first parameter for connect function holds the mapStateToProps function which essentially maps the application state to `props` of the `SignUp` component. Keeping that `null` means that you're expecting a `null` state object from Redux and hence you are unable to get the desired result in `this.props.args`. Removing `connect` statement makes the `props` which are passed down to the child component accessible through `this.props`. That's the crux of Redux.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Souvik . So the only solution would be to use a container component, to pass the connect and then use children's presentational components to pass my props? Or it is possible to use some other method, although I understand that it is not what is sought as a source of truth with redux.

The only thing that I can not understand because this.props.move (state that detects the movement of the mouse in the parent component) works.

Comment: `this.props` works inside your code because `this.props` refers to the component level state which you pass down from your parent component to its child component. Using `connect` necessarily means that the application's state is passed to your component which is in the form of `this.props`. Both are different. Keep that in mind. Thanks.